# How to copy a directory with its attributes/permissions from one location to another?

Tags: java-7, nio2

I see a lot of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10068306/14731) that use `Files.walkFileTree()` to copy a directory and its contents from one location to another, but they fail to take the directory's file attributes and permissions into consideration. Meaning, they just invoke `Files.createDirectories()` without any attributes or permissions.

How does one copy a directory (and its contents) from one location to another without losing file attributes or permissions, using the Java7 core classes?

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20085222/281545 and the vanilla one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, the examples you quoted do not copy file permissions (only attributes). They also do not copy directory permissions and attributes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```java
/**
 * Copies a directory.
 * <p>
 * NOTE: This method is not thread-safe.
 * <p>
 * 
 * @param source
 *            the directory to copy from
 * @param target
 *            the directory to copy into
 * @throws IOException
 *             if an I/O error occurs
 */
private static void copyDirectory(final Path source, final Path target)
        throws IOException {
    Files.walkFileTree(source, EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS),
        Integer.MAX_VALUE, new FileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                    BasicFileAttributes sourceBasic) throws IOException {
                Path targetDir = Files.createDirectories(target
                    .resolve(source.relativize(dir)));
                AclFileAttributeView acl = Files.getFileAttributeView(dir,
                    AclFileAttributeView.class);
                if (acl != null)
                    Files.getFileAttributeView(targetDir,
                        AclFileAttributeView.class).setAcl(acl.getAcl());
                DosFileAttributeView dosAttrs = Files.getFileAttributeView(
                    dir, DosFileAttributeView.class);
                if (dosAttrs != null) {
                    DosFileAttributes sourceDosAttrs = dosAttrs
                        .readAttributes();
                    DosFileAttributeView targetDosAttrs = Files
                        .getFileAttributeView(targetDir,
                            DosFileAttributeView.class);
                    targetDosAttrs.setArchive(sourceDosAttrs.isArchive());
                    targetDosAttrs.setHidden(sourceDosAttrs.isHidden());
                    targetDosAttrs.setReadOnly(sourceDosAttrs.isReadOnly());
                    targetDosAttrs.setSystem(sourceDosAttrs.isSystem());
                }
                FileOwnerAttributeView ownerAttrs = Files
                    .getFileAttributeView(dir, FileOwnerAttributeView.class);
                if (ownerAttrs != null) {
                    FileOwnerAttributeView targetOwner = Files
                        .getFileAttributeView(targetDir,
                            FileOwnerAttributeView.class);
                    targetOwner.setOwner(ownerAttrs.getOwner());
                }
                PosixFileAttributeView posixAttrs = Files
                    .getFileAttributeView(dir, PosixFileAttributeView.class);
                if (posixAttrs != null) {
                    PosixFileAttributes sourcePosix = posixAttrs
                        .readAttributes();
                    PosixFileAttributeView targetPosix = Files
                        .getFileAttributeView(targetDir,
                            PosixFileAttributeView.class);
                    targetPosix.setPermissions(sourcePosix.permissions());
                    targetPosix.setGroup(sourcePosix.group());
                }
                UserDefinedFileAttributeView userAttrs = Files
                    .getFileAttributeView(dir,
                        UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
                if (userAttrs != null) {
                    UserDefinedFileAttributeView targetUser = Files
                        .getFileAttributeView(targetDir,
                            UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
                    for (String key : userAttrs.list()) {
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(userAttrs
                            .size(key));
                        userAttrs.read(key, buffer);
                        buffer.flip();
                        targetUser.write(key, buffer);
                    }
                }
                // Must be done last, otherwise last-modified time may be
                // wrong
                BasicFileAttributeView targetBasic = Files
                    .getFileAttributeView(targetDir,
                        BasicFileAttributeView.class);
                targetBasic.setTimes(sourceBasic.lastModifiedTime(),
                    sourceBasic.lastAccessTime(),
                    sourceBasic.creationTime());
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                Files.copy(file, target.resolve(source.relativize(file)),
                    StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult
                    visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException e)
                            throws IOException {
                throw e;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                    IOException e) throws IOException {
                if (e != null) throw e;
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
}
```

This code hasn't been tested extensively, but it works for me.

Comment: Two questions : 1. why not the vanilla one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java 2. why not an implementation of SimpleFileVisitor

Comment: The design could also profit from an enum which would accept a Class<T extends FileAttributeView (or AttributeView)> in its constructor

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, the "vanilla one" copies attributes but not permissions. Which line(s) do you believe do so?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, I don't understand what you mean about the enum and constructor. `Class<T extends FileAttributeView>` is not an `enum`, nor is it clear what constructor you are referring to.

Comment: Re: enum: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngrwqnhzx7o7iqu/CopyDirectory.java. Re: the vanilla one - was just asking, I see now. Notice I changed the anonymous class to nested and made it implement SimpleFileVisitor (as visitFileFailed and postVisitDirectory) had the default behavior in your anonymous implementation

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, that's just a way of splitting up the code into smaller chunks. For the purposes of Stackoverflow, I think what we have is good enough.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D What is this essential library stuff? Is that from Oracle? In what library can it be found?

Comment: @Gili Is it still true that permissions aren't copied? From the tests I tried, posix permissions are copied over.

Comment: This is amazing! Still working on Java 9. Thankyou very much. I don't know about permissions but I only wanted to copy a simple directory anyway.