# Does Files.copy(Path,Path) create directories?

Tags: java, text-files, file-copying

I have a bunch of text files(say ss1.txt,ss2.txt,ss3.txt etc.) under a directory with my Java program (`C:/Users/java/dir1`)?
I want to move my txt files to a new directory that hasn't been created yet. I have a String address for all of my files and I think I can turn them into Paths using

**Path path = Paths.get(textPath);**

Would creating a String (`C:/Users/java/dir2`), turning that into a path using the above method and then using

***Files.copy(C:/Users/java/dir1/ss1.txt,C:/Users/java/dir2)***

result in `ss1.text` being copied to a new directory?

Comment: I just keep getting IO exceptions

Comment: Why not read their message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Method `Files.copy(C:/Users/java/dir1/ss1.txt,C:/Users/java/dir2)` will not create directory, it will create file dir2 in directory java that will contain ss1.txt data.

You could try it with this code:

```
File sourceFile = new File( "C:/Users/java/dir1/ss1.txt" );
Path sourcePath = sourceFile.toPath();

File destFile = new File( "C:/Users/java/dir2" );
Path destPath = destFile.toPath();

Files.copy( sourcePath, destPath );
```

Remember use java.nio.file.Files and java.nio.file.Path.

If you want to use class form java.nio to copy files from one directory to other you should use Files.walkFileTree(...) method. You can see solution here [Java: Using nio Files.copy to Move Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137849/java-using-nio-files-copy-to-move-directory).

Or you can simply use `FileUtils class from apache http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/ library, available since version 1.2.

```
File source = new File("C:/Users/java/dir1");
File dest = new File("C:/Users/java/dir2");
try {
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, *commons-io* library does not use the *java.nio* (at least, not for all the actions) package, but the *java.io*. I am saying this because you mentioned to use the *java.nio* package, but afterwards you mention the *commons-io* library. I would also recommend the *java.nio* because it has better file handling than *java.io* - I had some problems mostly with reading files that have special characters in their names which *nio* handled without problems.

Answer (score 27):

This is very easy with [Files.createDirectories()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))

```
Path source = Path.of("c:/dir/dir-x/file.ext");
Path target = Path.of("c:/target-dir/dir-y/target-file.ext");
Files.createDirectories(target.getParent());
Files.copy(path, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

And do not worry if the directories already exist, in that case it will do nothing and keep going...